Create Kessler Syndrome in Blender?
anyone have a good process to create a earth/satellite debris field (aka Kessler Syndrome)?
Example:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IOwv1j-fUbo&list=PLvjgztX_Uo3ZMUY9lGQZ6qIwZRiQw6LRR

Hello maybe check the particle boids?

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.
